# Solve system of equations, two different answers Elimination vs Substitution

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

So this is a problem from MIT Linear Algebra First Lecture TA Problem

$$\begin{cases}
2 x+y=3 \\
x-2 y=-1
\end{cases}$$

When you use substitution clearly the solution is

$$y= \dfrac15, x = \dfrac75$$

But if you multiply the second equation with (-2), then the solution is (1,1)

Why is there two solution for this system?

Comment: The solution must be unique , so at least one of the solutions is invalid. Check both ways again !

Comment: You can use latex formatting here, just enclose your code in \$ signs (or \$\$ for display mode).

Comment: We need to see both calculations to see where you could have made a mistake.

Comment: In fact, $(x,y)=(7/5,1/5)$ is *not* a solution of the second equation. Not sure about posting homework, though...

Comment: @TheoBendit I've overread that, sorry. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Check your work. There is only one solution.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, I found my silly mistake: On the second equation I was indeed putting equal to positive 1 and not negative 1, as it should be. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have spotted your mistake.

From the second equation, we can isolate $x$ to get

$$x = 2y - 1 $$

Then from here we do the usual thing and substitute this value of x into the other equation.

$$2(2y -1) + y = 3$$

Now the mistake comes in.

$$4y {\color{red} +} 2 + y= 3$$

And this one sign error leads you to the wrong answer. When corrected, the answer matches the one with elimination.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was giving up but certainly you made me look at it again, and yes the mistake was the negative sign on the second equation ("-1"), which i didn't put on my paper lol, thanks again!